# Proxy all sentry request in node application

Tags: node.js, networking, sentry

I have a `nodeJs` application which I want to use [`sentry`](http://sentry.io) in my application. I configured it properly but I want to proxy all my sentry requests. so how can I do this? can I do something like port forwarding, for example, all requests to `https://XXXXX@sentry.io` go through the specific machine in another host then redirect to `sentry.io`? how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure an HTTP(S) Proxy.

The [docs on sentry.io](https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/?platform=node#http-proxy) say:

> *httpProxy*
>
> When set a proxy can be configured that should be used for outbound requests. This is also used for HTTPS requests unless a separate https-proxy is configured. Note however that not all SDKs support a separate HTTPS proxy. SDKs will attempt to default to the system-wide configured proxy if possible. For instance, on unix systems, the http_proxy environment variable will be picked up.

There's a [dedicated option for https too, if you want different proxies](https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/?platform=node#https-proxy).